# Can someone advise me what wrong with my Type or linq query

Tags: c#, linq, list

I am hoping someone can help, my error is

> cannot implicitly convert type system.collections.generic.List to xxxlistlitems

I have this

```
public IDListItems getIDList()
{
    IDListItems items = new IDListItem();
    try
    {
        var x = (from c in db.ap_GetIDListItems()
               select new IDListItems { CId = c.CID, Id = c.ID }).ToList();
        items = x;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return items;   
}
```

and then I have a class like this

```
namespace SaSs
{
    public class IDListItems 
    {
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public string CId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I think its a issue with my return type but im unsure how to for the type to return a list

Comment: In future, please give a short but *complete* example, and the *actual* error message. (You clearly didn't copy and paste the error message, as the type name is incorrectly cased...)

Comment: You now have the solution, but I'd also add that using `catch (Exception ex) throw ex;` is a poor practice. Just delete your whole `catch` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set it as a list like this

```
List<IDListItems> items = new List<IDListItem>();
```

something like this should work

```
public List<IDListItems> GetIDList()
        {
            List<IDListItems> items = new List<IDListItems>();
        try
        {
            var x = (from c in db.ap_GetIDListItems()
                     select new IDListItems { CId = c.CID, Id = c.ID }).ToList();
            items = x;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return items;   
    }
```

if you calling the `GetIDList()` you will need to change this as well. you will need to add a proper catch statement to this as well.

Comment: While this will work, it's pretty horrible code - initializing a list for no reason, catching and rethrowing an exception, etc. It's pretty easy to turn this into *nice* code...

Comment: This was the best method in then end Thanks @AlanMorton2.0

Answer (score 3):

Erm... because items is not a list?

```
List<IDListItems> items = new List<IDListItem>();
```

Should do the trick..

Comment: Would be a seriously good idea to rename `IDListItems` to `IDListItem` so that the pluralization isn't confusing in the future.

Comment: Also need to check the return type of the `getIDList()` method.

Comment: Why would you suggest `List<IDListItems> items = new List<IDListItem>();` when `items` will simply be overwritten with `x`?

Comment: @DanielKelley I simply corrected his compilation error, this would not be my implementation, I would actually do what Jon Skeet did. Which I actually +1'ed

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro My point is you add far more value to the OP and SO by going the extra step and giving them the proper solution. This is why so many questions involving, for example, string concatenation for SQL queries are steered towards solutions involving SQL parameters rather than just fixing the concatenation issue.

Comment: @DanielKelley You are completely correct. I'll do better next time

Answer (score 3):

Others have suggested changing the type of the variable - I'd recommend removing the variable entirely, along with the pointless catch block. You do need to change the return type as well though:

```
public List<IDListItems> getIDList()
{
    return (from c in db.ap_GetIDListItems()
            select new IDListItems { CId = c.CID, Id = c.ID }).ToList();
}
```

Or without the somewhat pointless query expression:

```
public List<IDListItems> getIDList()
{
    return db.ap_GetIDListItems()
             .Select(c => new IDListItems { CId = c.CID, Id = c.ID })
             .ToList();
}
```

Comment: +1 as all the other answers still encourage the OP to create an instance of the type that will simply be discarded.

Comment: I am not sure this will work with WCF iv been trying it this way for the last hour to no joy.

Comment: @Mikey: What do you mean by "with WCF"? In a WCF service? With a LINQ implementation that calls WCF? You're not being very clear at all... and "to no joy" doesn't give us any indication of what problem you're facing.

Comment: @Jon Skeet I mean im writing the WCF API service, as appose to calling it, this would be the stored procedure call on the service program. it's ok, I have to implement the catch anyway for if it fails I can return a fail report, big thanks for your help,

Comment: @Mikey: You may need a catch block, but it certainly shouldn't look like the one in your question... and it's still not clear in what way my solution doesn't work for you. The fact that you're writing this in  a WCF service should be irrelevant. (You may need to expose the *results* in a different way, but that's got nothing to do with the question, really.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet yep I hadn't wrote the catch yet. the main issue was I could return the list which iv not fixed ill see tomorrow when im back in work

Comment: @Mikey - Then please read Eric Lippert's [too much reuse](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/04/too-much-reuse.aspx).  You're using `throw` incorrectly.  You should be using `catch(Exception){throw;/*Use $exception during debugging to access the exception*/}` or `catch(Exception ex){/*Use ex for stuff*/ throw;}`.

Answer (score 1):

items  is an `IDListItems`. You can't assign `IDListItems` to `List<IDListItems>`.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
public List<IDListItems> getIDList()
{

    List<IDListItems> items = new List<IDListItems>();

    try
    {
        var x = (from c in db.ap_GetIDListItems()
                 select new IDListItems { CId = c.CID, Id = c.ID }).ToList();
        items = x;
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return items;   
}
```